# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Func`1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having this issue in my View. The whole exception says:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
> ViewDataDictionary is of type
> 'System.Func`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Fogueo11.Models.Materias]]',
> but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Fogueo11.Models.Materias]'.

this is the Model:

```cs
using System;

namespace Fogueo11.Models
{
    public class Materias
    {
        public  string CodigoM { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Creditos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Fogueo11.Models.Materias>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CodigoM)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Creditos)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodigoM)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Creditos)
        </td>  
    </tr>
```

And this is action result:

```cs
public class CargarMaterias : Controller
{
    // GET: CargarMaterias
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Materias = from a in MateriaCursadas()
                       orderby a.CodigoM
                       select a;
        return View(MateriaCursadas);
    }
}
```

Can you guys explain what i am doing wrong?

I was trying to create a `List` in a model with the signatures that I'm currently taking, and send it to a View.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you are passing the wrong parameter to your view in your controller action by accident. Did you mean: `return View(Materias);`?

Comment: Wow Brother Thank you so much, didn't even realize of that.